# Non-event-driven socket module for Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've created a server with Node.js using Socket.io and now I need to let a Python client connect to it.

What troubles me is to understand how the "keywords" in Socket.io affects this connection. For example, this is how it is originally done on the server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('request', function(msg){
     console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

which means that the Python client would have to do something like this (if I were to run it as a script in the terminal):

```
establishConnection 12.12.12.12:3000 'connection'
//connection established ...
sendData('request', {data : 'hello'});
```

This is not preferable, and I need to modify the server to accept socket requests without the keywords, like this

```
establishConnection 12.12.12.12:3000
//connection established ...
sendData({data : 'hello'});
```

Is this possible to do with Socket.io?

Comment: well node.js is not python, but it doesnt mean its more complicated than python, its simpler once you understand why it uses callbacks and that pseudo-code looks so simple that i doubt anything like that could work.
you can make your application simpler by defining functions with arguments and just define the name as argument to where it should be used. take a look at this http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I should've pointed out that the "pseudo code" is really just something you would execute if you were running the script in a terminal. Also, my problem has nothing to do with callbacks. I need to be able to connect via sockets without using the event "keywords" in Socket.io, if you have any other module that lets me do this instead of Socket.io I would be happy to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, in the api, to get all packages from the `socket.io` library.

To get all packets from `socket.io` you can do an ugly hack and override [`onevent`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b3fc530abefd384b3a89ff5493e97f3ef85098d4/lib/socket.js#L326) or [`onpacket`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b3fc530abefd384b3a89ff5493e97f3ef85098d4/lib/socket.js#L291) of the `socket`.

Like this:

```
socket.onevent = function () {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

> { '0': { type: 2, nsp: '/', data: [ 'chat message', 'hei' ] } }

Note that this is undocumented, and unsupported, so the API might very likely break.